# MS Excel: Count Number of Words Between Two Different Characters in a Text String

Tags: excel, count, character, between, words

I am looking for a MS Excel (2007 or 2010) formula that will return the number of words found between two (2) specific characters within a text string.

Example (In Cell A2):  John Doe purchased a pizza for $13.00 using his 10% discount coupon on his order.

I would like to Count the number words separated by spaces between the "$" (dollar symbol) and the "%" (percent symbol); including the words containing the specific characters.

Results (In Cell B2): The formula in cell A2 returns a value of four (4) to reflect that the string contains four words ($13.00 using his 10%) separated by "$" and "%".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in B2, changing "%" and "$" as required:

```
=LEN(MID(B2,FIND("$",B2)+1,FIND("%",B2)-FIND("$",B2)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,FIND("$",B2)+1,FIND("%",B2)-FIND("$",B2)-1)," ",""))+1
```

Comment: Hi S O,  I would like to thank you so very much for your courteous and fast reply, to accurately answer my MS Excel Count Words formula is greatly appreciated and it works absolutely well.... Thanks again and again.

Comment: Hi S O, I would like to know using the same principal is there a MS Excel formula that will allow me to also Extract only the words found between the between two (2) characters/delimiters (i.e., "$" (dollar symbol) and the "%" (percent symbol).  This would also include extracting the whole words containing both delimiters.  Results would return Cell B2: $13.00 using his 10%?

Comment: `=MID(B2,FIND("$",B2),FIND("%",B2)-FIND("$",B2))`

Comment: Hi S O, Again, you're truly a life saver... lol.  Your provided MS Excel formula works like a charm, and as usual.  THANK YOU!!!